# Extract number followed and preceded by the words

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Extract numbers followed and preceded by words:

```
String q = 'Consumer spending in the US rose to about 62% of GDP in 1960, where it stayed until about 1981, and has since risen to 71% in 2013'
q = re.findall(r'^([^\d]+)\s(\d+)\s*,\s*([^\d]+)\s(\d+)',s)
```

it gives the list of all words and numbers in the gives `q`.
so now i want method to get number along with words

Comment: What is your expected output here?

Comment: Why is this tagged ``python`` when it looks like ``Java``?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description I guess you need something like this:

```
>>> import re
>>> strs = 'Consumer spending in the US rose to about 62% of GDP in 1960, where it stayed until about 1981, and has since risen to 71% in 2013'
>>> re.findall(r'\w+\s\d+.*?\s\w+',strs)
['about 62% of', 'in 1960, where', 'about 1981, and', 'to 71% in']
```

Comment: @RahulRanjan Is this is what you wanted or should I remove the solution?